# AFNetworking set default value for POST request

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking

I'm trying to using `AFNetworking` after the switch from `ASIHTTPRequest`.

I would use `AFHTTPClient` for making request to my api backend server. Currently I make a request (without `AFNetworking`) for getting the csrf token (I use Django) before **every** POST request with `AFNetworking` (I get it from `www.example.org/api/csrf`). I do this because I need the csrf token for every POST request.

Is there a way to make this task automatically in the `AFHTTPClient`?

EDIT:

The code for getting the csrf token before every POST request is:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kTokenURL]];
NSData *jsonData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [jsonString objectFromJSONString];
NSString *csrf_token  = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"csrf_token"];
[jsonString release];
NSLog(@"token: %@", csrf_token);
```

Comment: Not sure how you are getting the csrf token (some code would be nice :) ) but I would subclass the AFHTTPClient so that each time you have to make a post request, getting the csrf token is automatically done for you (in your subclass). There is an example of this in the AFGowallaAPIClient project.

Comment: I updated my question. Btw I need the csrf token only for POST request. Is it possible to set it only for these type of requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, create a AFHTTPClient Subclass (there is an example of this in the example project that comes with AFNetworking)

In your @interface file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AFHTTPClient.h"

@interface HttpClientSubclass : AFHTTPClient
    + (HttpClientSubclass *)sharedClient;
@end
```

In your implementation file:

```
#import "HttpClientSubclass.h"

@implementation HttpClientSubclass


+ (HttpClientSubclass *)sharedClient {
    static HttpClientSubclass *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
    _sharedClient = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"BASE-URL-GOES_HERE"]];
});

    return _sharedClient;
}

- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method 
                                  path:(NSString *)path 
                            parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters { 

if ([method isEqualToString:@"POST"])
    //GET YOUR CSRF TOKEN HERE, AND PASS ONTO THE SUPER CLASS IN THE PARAMETERS

return [super requestWithMethod:method path:path parameters:parameters];

}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks. So should I get the csrf token in the `if ([method isEqualToString:@"POST"])` and after that should I add a new key/value pair in the `parameters` dictionary before the return statement? Thanks guy!

Comment: Yeah that's it. Then when you call it from your program, you can use the shared singleton pointer instead of having to instantiate in each class.